# Why are some on-chain transactions marked RED on RTL (Ride the Lightning)

Tags: transactions, lightning-network-daemon

I have an [LND](https://github.com/LightningNetwork/lnd) node and I use [RTL](https://github.com/Ride-The-Lightning/RTL) to interface with it.
I noticed that for some of the on-chain transactions, the `Amount(Sats)` value is marked in RED, why so? What happened with those transactions?

Here some examples

[image]

Here are the details of the first RED transaction in the list

[image]

Here is the text version of the second image for convenience

```
Transaction Information

Block Hash
0000000000000000000cf17b104e7dd126912b6f328c139c03fbfa186eea089b

Transaction Hash
c3785a1874c09c3185acdd2c2ccc41541b11b4df430c4cd0ae169636e631aa5a

Label
0:openchannel:shortchanid-759295242403315713

Date/Time
11/JUL/2021 14:46

Block Height
690,575

Number of Confirmations
7,706

Total Fees (Sats)
5,157

Amount (Sats)
-505,157

Destination Addresses
bc1q258zrm82w9qg96uv2jv23px38hj994h6erh0f3
bc1qgfw2cchk2naxxtgte82k54gvgwqf0fnsyj0nh7ecfgaa7uzlye4qy3x9uh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is standard accounting practice in the US to show negative numbers in parentheses. I'd guess that the values here in parentheses and red show outgoing payments, while the ones in white without parentheses show incoming payments.